Using DLL files and lazy loading them rather than using a Project Reference
I have a main project called "Core" and another project called "tool". "Core" has a reference to "tool", and the tool is displayed in Core's UI.
In the core.csproj, I am using lazy loading and referencing the project as follows:
<ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="Tool.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad Include="Tool.wasm" />
</ItemGroup>

Instead of this, I want to use the DLL file directly. I was able to achieve this using:
AssemblyLoader.LoadAssembliesAsync("path to dll");

However, this approach results in the following error:
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Error: Tool.dll must be marked with 'BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad' item group in your project file to allow lazy-loading.
Error: Tool.dll must be marked with 'BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad' item group in your project file to allow lazy-loading.

How do I solve this error?

What do you mean by "lazy loading"? What do you hope to achieve? Performance? some kind of plugin?

So basically I have multiple tools as different projects and They show up as cards on the UI. When you click on the tool that's when the tool is loaded. So it's for performance.

I have not used webasm, but .Net do not load or compile things before they are needed. So I'm kind of doubtful that your idea will help.

In Blazor assemblies load up on the start of the application and these tools are all assemblies so they have to be lazy loaded if not the startup time would be a lot.

"Tool.dll must be marked with 'BlazorWebAssemblyLazyLoad' item group in your project file to allow lazy-loading" well what happened when you tried? You still have the normal <ProjectReference Include="Tool.csproj" /> there.
